# Many buttons, jquery

Tags: jquery

**jQuery**:

```
$("#direction").click(function() {
    var direction = $(this).text();
    alert(direction);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="direction">South</button>
<button id="direction">North</button>
```

Only the first button alerts the text. I don't understand why. How can I fix this?

Comment: u are using ID selector .if jquery engine find more than one element with same ID it ignores all except first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have two elements with the same id, what you could do is give them the same class and then add the event handler on that.

Example:

```
<button class="directionBtn">South</button>
<button class="directionBtn">North</button>

$(".directionBtn").click(function() {
                var direction = $(this).text();
                alert(direction);
});
```

Comment: This code contains syntax error, missing '}' and ')' at the end

Comment: We can agree that syntax is not part of the answer. This was more explaining a concept (use `class` instead of `id`). But you're right and I edited my answer to fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

It's invalid to have multiple elements with the same `id` (an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document); as jQuery presumably implements `document.getElementById()` internally, this will only ever (correctly) return the first element it encounters with that `id`.

In your case you should use a `class` of direction, and select based upon that:

```
$('.direction').click(
    function(){/*...*/});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two elements with the same id, use classes if you want to reference multiple elements at once, something like:

```
<button class="direction">South</button>
<button class="direction">North</button>
```

And then in your script:

```
 $(".direction").click(function() {
    var direction = $(this).text();
    alert(direction);
});
```

Comment: To be clear, you CAN have two elements with the same ID. It's just a very bad idea to do so as it will create problems.